# cURL CONNECTTIMEOUT alert

Tags: c++, curl

i am doing this project in which a small part is to connect to a server and do some things and if it fails to connect to the server within a time, then give an error message..
i know the curl code looks something like this
curl_easy_setopt(c,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,1L);
and also that it has a MilliSecond option. What i want is for the program to alert me if curl fails to connect to the server within the given time(in this case 1 second.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
char* pErrorBuffer = NULL;
pErrorBuffer = (char*)malloc( 512 );
memset( pErrorBuffer, 0, 512 );
curl_easy_setopt( curlHandle, CURLOPT_ERRORBUFFER, pErrorBuffer );
curl_easy_setopt( curlHandle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1 ); // 1 s connect timeout
if( CURLE_OK != curl_easy_perform( curlHandle ) )
{
    // pErrorBuffer contains error string returned by cURL
    pErrorBuffer[511] = '\0';
    printf( "cURL returned: %s", pErrorBuffer );
}
// Free when you're done.
free( pErrorBuffer );
```